# Append to number using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a number coming as an element in xml.
I need to append 0's to make it 5 digit number.
Like if it is 1,then i need to convert to 00001
If it is 12, then i need to convert to 00012
If it is 123,then i need to convert to 00123
If it is 1234,then i need to convert to 01234

Input

```
<id>23</id>
```

Output

```
<id>00123</id>
```

Instead of writing conditions multiple times how to do it in single condition using xslt

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: we are using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your input is strictly numeric, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(id, '00000')"/>
```

Comment: If it isn't strictly numeric, you could do something like this instead: `<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('00000',string-length()+1),.)"/>`